# Weird Error, error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, character, double-pointer

Every time I try to compile this (error on line 110)

```
   #include <iostream>
std::string anything;
int end;
char page1[10] [10];
char Pix1;
char Pix2;
char Pix3;
char Pix4;
char Pix5;
char Pix6;
char Pix7;
char Pix8;
char Pix9;
char Pix10;
char Pix11;
char Pix12;
char Pix13;
char Pix14;
char Pix15;
char Pix16;
char Pix17;
char Pix18;
char Pix19;
char Pix20;
char Pix21;
char Pix22;
char Pix23;
char Pix24;
char Pix25;
char Pix26;
char Pix27;
char Pix28;
char Pix29;
char Pix30;
char Pix31;
char Pix32;
char Pix33;
char Pix34;
char Pix35;
char Pix36;
char Pix37;
char Pix38;
char Pix39;
char Pix40;
char Pix41;
char Pix42;
char Pix43;
char Pix44;
char Pix45;
char Pix46;
char Pix47;
char Pix48;
char Pix49;
char Pix50;
char Pix51;
char Pix52;
char Pix53;
char Pix54;
char Pix55;
char Pix56;
char Pix57;
char Pix58;
char Pix59;
char Pix60;
char Pix61;
char Pix62;
char Pix63;
char Pix64;
char Pix65;
char Pix66;
char Pix67;
char Pix68;
char Pix69;
char Pix70;
char Pix71;
char Pix72;
char Pix73;
char Pix74;
char Pix75;
char Pix76;
char Pix77;
char Pix78;
char Pix79;
char Pix80;
char Pix81;
char Pix82;
char Pix83;
char Pix84;
char Pix85;
char Pix86;
char Pix87;
char Pix88;
char Pix89;
char Pix90;
char Pix91;
char Pix92;
char Pix93;
char Pix94;
char Pix95;
char Pix96;
char Pix97;
char Pix98;
char Pix99;
char Pix100;
std::string PageNumber;
using namespace std;

int main(){
//Reset level into Screen Mem
page1 [0] [0] = "T";
if(PageNumber == "page1"){
     Pix1 = page1 [0] [0];
     Pix2 = page1 [0] [1];
     Pix3 = page1 [0] [2];
     Pix4 = page1 [0] [3];
     Pix5 = page1 [0] [4];
     Pix6 = page1 [0] [5];
     Pix7 = page1 [0] [6];
     Pix8 = page1 [0] [7];
     Pix9 = page1 [0] [8];
     Pix10 = page1 [0] [9];
     Pix11 = page1 [1] [0];
     Pix12 = page1 [1] [1];
     Pix13 = page1 [1] [2];
     Pix14 = page1 [1] [3];
     Pix15 = page1 [1] [4];
     Pix16 = page1 [1] [5];
     Pix17 = page1 [1] [6];
     Pix18 = page1 [1] [7];
     Pix19 = page1 [1] [8];
     Pix20 = page1 [1] [9];
     Pix21 = page1 [2] [0];
     Pix22 = page1 [2] [1];
     Pix23 = page1 [2] [2];
     Pix24 = page1 [2] [3];
     Pix25 = page1 [2] [4];
     Pix26 = page1 [2] [5];
     Pix27 = page1 [2] [6];
     Pix28 = page1 [2] [7];
     Pix29 = page1 [2] [8];
     Pix30 = page1 [2] [9];
     Pix31 = page1 [3] [0];
     Pix32 = page1 [3] [1];
     Pix33 = page1 [3] [2];
     Pix34 = page1 [3] [3];
     Pix35 = page1 [3] [4];
     Pix36 = page1 [3] [5];
     Pix37 = page1 [3] [6];
     Pix38 = page1 [3] [7];
     Pix39 = page1 [3] [8];
     Pix40 = page1 [3] [9];
     Pix41 = page1 [4] [0];
     Pix42 = page1 [4] [1];
     Pix43 = page1 [4] [2];
     Pix44 = page1 [4] [3];
     Pix45 = page1 [4] [4];
     Pix46 = page1 [4] [5];
     Pix47 = page1 [4] [6];
     Pix48 = page1 [4] [7];
     Pix49 = page1 [4] [8];
     Pix50 = page1 [4] [9];
     Pix51 = page1 [5] [0];
     Pix52 = page1 [5] [1];
     Pix53 = page1 [5] [2];
     Pix54 = page1 [5] [3];
     Pix55 = page1 [5] [4];
     Pix56 = page1 [5] [5];
     Pix57 = page1 [5] [6];
     Pix58 = page1 [5] [7];
     Pix59 = page1 [5] [8];
     Pix60 = page1 [5] [9];
     Pix61 = page1 [6] [0];
     Pix62 = page1 [6] [1];
     Pix63 = page1 [6] [2];
     Pix64 = page1 [6] [3];
     Pix65 = page1 [6] [4];
     Pix66 = page1 [6] [5];
     Pix67 = page1 [6] [6];
     Pix68 = page1 [6] [7];
     Pix69 = page1 [6] [8];
     Pix70 = page1 [6] [9];
     Pix71 = page1 [7] [0];
     Pix72 = page1 [7] [1];
     Pix73 = page1 [7] [2];
     Pix74 = page1 [7] [3];
     Pix75 = page1 [7] [4];
     Pix76 = page1 [7] [5];
     Pix77 = page1 [7] [6];
     Pix78 = page1 [7] [7];
     Pix79 = page1 [7] [8];
     Pix80 = page1 [7] [9];
     Pix81 = page1 [8] [0];
     Pix82 = page1 [8] [1];
     Pix83 = page1 [8] [2];
     Pix84 = page1 [8] [3];
     Pix85 = page1 [8] [4];
     Pix86 = page1 [8] [5];
     Pix87 = page1 [8] [6];
     Pix88 = page1 [8] [7];
     Pix89 = page1 [8] [8];
     Pix90 = page1 [8] [9];
     Pix91 = page1 [9] [0];
     Pix92 = page1 [9] [1];
     Pix93 = page1 [9] [2];
     Pix94 = page1 [9] [3];
     Pix95 = page1 [9] [4];
     Pix96 = page1 [9] [5];
     Pix97 = page1 [9] [6];
     Pix98 = page1 [9] [7];
     Pix99 = page1 [9] [8];
     Pix100 = page1 [9] [9];
}
//Screen Print
cout << Pix1 << Pix2 << Pix3 << Pix4 << Pix5 << Pix6 << Pix7 << Pix8 << Pix9 << Pix10 << endl;
cout << Pix11 << Pix12 << Pix13 << Pix14 << Pix15 << Pix16 << Pix17 << Pix18 << Pix19 << Pix20 << endl;
cout << Pix21 << Pix22 << Pix23 << Pix24 << Pix25 << Pix26 << Pix27 << Pix28 << Pix29 << Pix30 << endl;
cout << Pix31 << Pix32 << Pix33 << Pix34 << Pix35 << Pix36 << Pix37 << Pix38 << Pix39 << Pix40 << endl;
cout << Pix41 << Pix42 << Pix43 << Pix44 << Pix45 << Pix46 << Pix47 << Pix48 << Pix49 << Pix50 << endl;
cout << Pix51 << Pix52 << Pix53 << Pix54 << Pix55 << Pix56 << Pix57 << Pix58 << Pix59 << Pix60 << endl;
cout << Pix61 << Pix62 << Pix63 << Pix64 << Pix65 << Pix66 << Pix67 << Pix68 << Pix69 << Pix70 << endl;
cout << Pix71 << Pix72 << Pix73 << Pix74 << Pix75 << Pix76 << Pix77 << Pix78 << Pix79 << Pix80 << endl;
cout << Pix81 << Pix82 << Pix83 << Pix84 << Pix85 << Pix86 << Pix87 << Pix88 << Pix89 << Pix90 << endl;
cout << Pix91 << Pix92 << Pix93 << Pix94 << Pix95 << Pix96 << Pix97 << Pix98 << Pix99 << Pix100 << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I get this error 110:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive] 
I want the 2d array (line 4) to not be a const char,
HELP!
-Lijrobert

Comment: Why do you have 100 variables rather than char Pix[100]? Or even just two for-loops to print out from page1 directly?

Comment: First I have no idea why I didn't do Pix[100] and I want to be able to control whether I print page1 or page5*.                                 *Page5 is an example of an array in the future

Comment: WTF! Have you heard of **loops** and **arrays**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a 2D array thus.

```
char page1[10] [10];
```

It means only characters can be stored in it.
Store the character in this way in it.

```
page1[0] [0] = 'T';
```

What you are doing now is.

```
char page1[0] [0] = "T" ;
```

Whatever you write inside double quotes "", it is constant cstring (char*). and whatever you write inside single quotes '', it is a single character.
You can store a character on one index of a [2D array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-dimensional_array), not a whole cstring.

Comment: Hey, can you help me with one more thing. Can you tell me why my display system isn't working. I insert stuff into level memory and it doesn't go to display memory

Comment: @user68537: What is "level memory"? If you have a new question, you should ask a new question. And we'll need a lot more context than that to answer it.

Comment: Ok, I'll ask a new question. Just to explain I call the 2D char array Level memory and all the and all the variables that get displayed at the end display memory

Comment: What's inside the quotes when you type: "your string here" is a **string literal**, which is a sequence of characters surrounded by double quotes, optionally prefixed by an encoding prefix (u8, R, etc). A string literal with no encoding prefix is also called a narrow string literal. A narrow string literal has type **array of n const char**, where n is the size of the string and has static storage duration, that means the type is: **const char[strlen("your string here")]** which decays to a **const char*** which is a pointer to the first character in the array.